# Getting NotAMockException instead of assertion failure when changing verification mode or expected arguments PowerMock verifyStatic calls

Tags: java, mockito, powermock

I have a test which verifies a static method was called with certain arguments

```
@PowerMockIgnore({"javax.management.*"})
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({MyUtil.class})
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
public class MyTest {
    @Test
    public void Test() {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(MyUtil.class);
        when(MyUtil.doStaticMethod(any(), any())).thenReturn("value");
        // do test
        ...
        verifyStatic(MyUtil.class, times(1));
        MyUtil.doStaticMethod("a", "b");
    }
}
```

This works fine if the method is called once with arguments "a" and "b", however if I change verification to either `times(2)` or `"aa", "b"` instead of getting a test failure error I get

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.NotAMockException: Argument should be a mock, but is: class java.lang.Class

    at org.powermock.core.MockGateway.doMethodCall(MockGateway.java:182)
    at org.powermock.core.MockGateway.doMethodCall(MockGateway.java:164)
    at org.powermock.core.MockGateway.methodCall(MockGateway.java:141)
    at com.mycompany.project.MyUtil.doStaticMethod(S3ServiceUtil.java)
    at ...
```

I am using powermock 1.7.4 and mockito 2.8.9 and have mock-maker-inline configured for final class instrumentation. I haven't been able to find anything, any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: From the [docs](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mockito#how-to-verify-behavior) *`Important: You need to call verifyStatic(Static.class) per method verification.`*